# How do I weight Win/Loss Percentage Based on Games Played?

Tags: statistics

I have a spreadsheet I use for tracking my statistics in a game across a number of different factors such as Map, Group Size and Class.

In each case, I use the win percentage to determine a rating out of 5 (rounded to the nearest $.01$). For example, when playing with a friend, I have a win percentage of $44\%$, this translates to an overall rating of $2.20$ in my current spreadsheet. Likewise, when playing alone, I have a win percentage of $49.64\%$ which translates to a rating of $2.48$.

I have $50$ games played with 2 people and $137$ games played alone.

I would like to adjust the rating to reflect the number of games played, such that a win percentage of $50\%$ over $100$ games will be rated higher than $50\%$ over $50$ games.

I'm not quite sure how to approach this. Has anyone any suggestions or places I can turn to to help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current rating is proportional to an estimate of the winning probability. You appear to be interested in a pessimistic estimate, so as to favour more precise measurements.

This can be done by basing it on the lower end of a [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval). For instance, if we use the lower bound of the [Wilson score interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval) with a confidence level of 90%, we get

- 38.7% for 25/50 (rating of 1.93)
- 41.9% for 50/100 (rating of 2.09)

Choose the interval and tune the confidence level to your taste. The greater the confidence level, the more skeptic the rating.

An alternative is to use a Bayesian approach. Starting with a pessimistic prior (lower values being more probable), update it and make your rating proportional to some average of the resulting distribution.

For example, if we start with [Beta(1, 10)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Bayesian_inference) and rate on the expected value, we get

- $\frac{26}{61}$ for 25/50 (rating of 2.13)
- $\frac{51}{111}$ for 50/100 (rating of 2.30)

Similarly, tune $\beta$ to your preference. A larger $\beta$ means a more pessimistic prior.

In choosing, you might want to consider how you would like your rating to behave in extreme cases such as 0/1, 0/2, 0/20, 1/1, 2/2, 20/20.